# I am not able to add background image to my jsp file through css code

Tags: html, css, jsp, background-image

html code goes like this in my jsp file

```
<div class="itemadd">
        <div class="blur">
        </div>
</div>
```

the css code is:

```
.itemadd {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(image/home.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .blur {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    }
```

I have checked the names of file and folder correctly and there is no typing mistake while writing the code.

However, if I try to add background image implicitly through html code it works but that causes problem as I am not able to add linear-gradient property.

I also, coded it in VS CODE and it works perfectly there, but the same doesn't in JSP eclipse

Edit:
I tried to write my css code like:

```
 .itemadd {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('./image/home.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
        }
.blur{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100vh;
       backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
     }
```

still the problem didn't get resolved. I am attaching the folder structure of my project. The css file I am working on is menuadd.css (It is highlighted in the folder). My css is connected to my html page. All css code is working fine, except for the code I have written above.

[image: folder structure]

Comment: try this: 
  url('./image/home.jpg');  if it doesn't work Edit your Question and share the Project Folder Structure(screenshot) .

Comment: @naveen4181 It didn't worked. I added the project folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying the solution Go through the below image and the Link Provided.

[image: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp]

Reference Link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Note: Understand the hierarchy firstly as the jsp/html page are with the webapp folder, image folder contains images,css folder contains css file,
'**image/home.jpg**' URL will work in jsp and html pages as they are not stored in any sub folder,but when you try access image from css folder the hierarchy changes , you are accessing image folder from css folder,so firstly you have come out css folder(1 Level Up) which is denoted by  '**../**'

Try This:

[image: Folder Structure]

Inside menuadd.css :

```
.itemadd {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(../image/home.jpg);
background-size: cover;
  }

.blur {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
 backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
      }
```

Inside Jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
       
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menuadd.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="itemadd">
        <div class="blur">
        </div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```